# How to shuffle 2d array such that I have constant amount different elements before and after the shuffle?

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

Below is the Fisher-Yates algorithm that I used to shuffle, but as an output I'm getting a varying amount of differently typed objects. 
Here since I cannot swap according to position, I swapped the type of objects.

```
public static String shuffle(Grid grid) {

    Random rnd = new Random();

    for(int i=grid.getGridSize()-1;i>0;i--) {
        for(int j=grid.getGridSize()-1;j>0;j--) {
            int x = rnd.nextInt(i+1);
            int y = rnd.nextInt(j+1);
            CardType temp = grid.getTypeAt(x, y);

            grid.getCardAt(i, j).setType(temp);
            grid.getCardAt(x, y).setType(grid.getTypeAt(i, j));
            if(grid.getCardAt(x, y).isFlipped()^(grid.getCardAt(i,j).isFlipped())) {
                grid.flipCardAt(i, j);   
                grid.flipCardAt(x, y);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you need really to change the object? I would recommend creating a new one with the final shuffling applied. Do you have an input and output examples?

Comment: I am not allowed to create new object and use any sorts of collections.sort().

Comment: You probably need to create temporary variables and assign the value to be modified before changing it.

Comment: i renamed my Temporary variable to temp, which should function as the name implies.

Comment: You need swap the lines assigning i, j and x, y.

Comment: i swapped its type since i cannot deal here  wth position swap.

Comment: i used setType to swap the objects type

Comment: simply put i donot have setCardAt() method.

Comment: Thanks @Jai .It helped!